# Uiautomatorviewer is giving error "SWT folder '..\lib\location of your Java installation.' does not exist"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-uiautomator

I have installed Android studio V 3.1.1

i am trying to launch UIautoamtorviewer.bat file from

```
C:\Users\panmishr\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin
```

however it always gives me error

```
SWT folder '..\framework\location of your Java installation.' does not exist.Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
```

below are list of env variables , which i have set

```
ANDROID_HOME: C:\Users\panmishr\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
ANDROID_SWT:C:\Users\panmishr\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\x86_64
JAVA_HOME :C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171
```

in Path Variable , i have included

```
C:\Users\panmishr\App;C:\Users\panmishr\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools
C:\Users\panmishr\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

My machine is 64 bit windows 7 .

Let me know, what i have missed.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to resolve this with the help of **sdkmanager.bat**

Go to bin folder `C:\Users\panmishr\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin` and run

```
sdkmanager.bat
```

It will give the correct error, like in my case `JAVA_HOME` path was set to old path in registry.

Run

```
regedit
```

Search `JAVA_HOME`

Delete the old `JAVA_HOME` key and value.

Log off the machine

Run

```
uiautomatorviewer.bat
```

This time it worked!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

1: I have installed **jdk 8**.

2: Go to **environment variables** -> **System variables** -> Click **New** and add following:

```
 Variable Name: ANDROID_SWT
 Variable Value: C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\x86_64
```

Make sure to replace Username with your own user.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhdb0.png)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had the same problem because I was changed my JVM and I didn´t restart the PC afther that. So the only think that I did was restart the computer and all the regedit files was update

Comment: restarting solely your pc is not a real solution.

Comment: If restarting is what fixed it for them, why is that not a real solution? That suggestion could help someone who didn't consider it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem with below Steps:

1. set ANDROID_SWT = "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\x86_64"
   { The mentioned location is where swt.jar is located.}
2. Open CMD -> run uiautomatorviewer

It works !!

Answer (score 0):

From my research Uiautomatorviewer works only with the version Java 8. So any version above 8 will not work. I had Java 17 installed and had to uninstall it.

You can download the the previous version of Java at this link from the official Oracle website:

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html

Download the x86 version relative to you operating system. (For example I am using a Windows and downloaded: jdk-8u291-windows-i586.exe)

Now you have to configure the environment variables for "JAVA_PATH". To access this on Windows click on file explorer, right click, and select "properties".

On the right side of the windows form, select "Advanced system settings."
Click "Environment Variables" near the lower right corner of the window.

At this screen set "JAVA_HOME" to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_291" as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

From here, restart the computer and go the cmd and enter uiautomatorviewer.

[image]

This fixed the issue for me. Be sure to have your emulator turned on and remember to shut off the appium server when you are taking a screenshot of the emulator.